# How to pivot my table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table database like this :

[image]

i want to make on table view like this :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You should post textual data along with what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need it per year basis.

```
Select year, id_lesson,
Sum(case when term = 1 then exam_1 end) exam_1_term_1,
Sum(case when term = 1 then exam_2 end) exam_2_term_1,
Sum(case when term = 2 then exam_1 end) exam_1_term_2,
Sum(case when term = 2 then exam_2 end) exam_2_term_2,
Sum(case when term = 3 then exam_1 end) exam_1_term_3,
Sum(case when term = 3 then exam_2 end) exam_2_term_3
From your_table
Group by id_lesson, year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic, Hope it is help.

```
$qdata = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID_Lesson");

$rows = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($qdata) > 0) {

    // Store all exam based on ID_Lesson ar array

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qdata)) {

        if (!isset($row[$data['ID_Lesson']])) {

            $rows[$data['ID_Lesson']] = array($data['ID_Lesson'], $data['Exam1'], $data['Exam2']);
        }
        else {

            $rows[$data['ID_Lesson']][] = $data['Exam1'];
            $rows[$data['ID_Lesson']][] = $data['Exam2'];
        }
    }

    $html = '';

    // Print per element as <tr> row
    foreach ($rows as $k => $row) {

        $html .= "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $row) . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```